# When reading a txt file with VBScript, why do we use Const conForReading?

Tags: file, vbscript

I noticed other people using ForReading instead of conForReading in other codes, but I tried and they do not seem interchangeable . What is the difference between these two? I am new at VBScript, sorry if it is an obvious question. I am using it in the following:

```
Option Explicit

Const conForReading = 1;
'Declare variables
Dim objFSO, objReadFile, contents

'Set Objects
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\ali\Desktop\Tests\ToRead.txt",1, False)
```

I would appreciate the clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenTextFile method supports several modifiers to achieve different goals. 
The second parameter called "iomode" specifies whether a file should be read, overwritten or appended to.
As there is no enumeration type in vbscript the this is differentiated through an integer.
As you can see [in the documentation of the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

```
1 means read
2 means write
8 means append
```

While it is perfectly fine from the programs point of view to write 1,2 and 8 as the parameter, this is a little problematic for humans. If you read another persons code (or even your own at a later point) and you just see

```
... OpenTextFile( "....", 1, ...)
```

you might not really know what that 1 means there. So people thought it would be a good idea to define a variable for that called ForReading which just makes the code more understandable. If you do that you can write:

```
... OpenTextFile( "....", ForReading, ...)
```

and immediately know whats going on although the code stays the same for the interpreter.
Now as JosefZ pointed out there are some predefined constants already, but those 3 are not amongst them. Because of that you define them yourself (as you can also see in the example on the msdn page I linked)

The reason why you would use a constant and not a variable is to prevent programming errors where you accidentally change the value of those. It would never make sense for "ForReading" to be not 1 so, as a constant the scripting engine will warn you if you ever try to change the value.

Now some people mark their constants by following the convention that all of them start with "con" so they can identify them in the code easily.

This is basically the reason why there is ForReading and conForReading. It is however the same. You can call it however you want the important thing is that is has the value 1 and that you use the one that you defined. If you define conForReading in your script you can not use ForReading in the function call.

Other people also always define the 3 constants

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
```

even if the only use one. This might be confusing for beginners as it looks like those constants would be needed if they are not even called. The reason why they do this is probably because they either just copy code form some example or another of their programs or for completeness so that it is well documented what could possibly be used in the function. Another reason could be that in a bigger script you might need all of them anyway and if you include them at the beginning you can never make the mistake of using one and not having it defined.

As for your example code:
You are not using the constant at all in your function call so it would not even change something if you leave it out.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really clarified my question. For the people who look at this question and are looking for the exact answer, it is that "some people mark their constants by following the convention that all of them start with "con" so they can identify them in the code easily.

This is basically the reason why there is ForReading and conForReading. It is however the same. You can call it however you want the important thing is that is has the value 1 and that you use the one that you defined. If you define conForReading in your script you can not use ForReading in the function call."

Answer (score 1):

Constants provide a convenient way to use specific values (instead of their literal values) without actually having to remember the value itself. Using constants also makes your code more readable and maintainable.

Some constants are already defined in `VBScript`, you don't need to explicitly declare them in your code. Simply use them in place of the values they represent. Here are the various categories of constants provided in VBScript and a brief description of each (with examples):

- *Color* Constants: eight basic colors that can be used in scripting (e.g. `vbRed`, `vbCyan`, ...).
- *Comparison* Constants: used to compare strings (`vbBinaryCompare`, `vbTextCompare`).
- *Date and Time* Constants: used by various date and time functions (`vbFriday`, ...).
- *Date Format* Constants: used to format dates and times (`vbLongDate`, `vbShortTime`, ...).
- *MsgBox* Constants: used in the MsgBox function to describe button visibility, labeling, behavior, and return values (`vbOKOnly`, `vbOK`, ...).
- *String* Constants: a variety of non-printable characters used in string manipulation (`vbTab`, `vbNewLine`, ...).
- *Tristate* Constants: used with functions that format numbers.
- *VarType* Constants: the various Variant subtypes (`vbNull`, `vbDate`, ...).
- *Miscellaneous* Constants that don't conveniently fit into any other category (`vbObjectError`).

Regrettably, `VBScript` does not use enumerated constants (i.e. predefined data structures like in `typedef enum BrowserNavConstants`, e.g. `navOpenInNewWindow`, `navOpenInNewTab`, ...): you must either (better) define them explicitly in your code:

```
Const navOpenInNewWindow=&h01, navOpenInNewTab=&h0800
```

or (worse) use the numeric literal values (`&h01`, `&h0800`, ...) in place of the constant names...

Eventually, you could define your own constants naming them as you like:

```
'various useful constants
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const OpenAsDefault = -2  ' Opens the file using the system default.
Const OpenAsUnicode = -1  ' Opens the file as Unicode.
Const OpenAsUSAscii =  0  ' Opens the file as ASCII.
Const DontCreate =  False ' do not create a new file if doesn't exist
Const CreateFile =  True  ' create a new file if the specified filename doesn't exist

Const RabbitEars = """"

'Registry Data Types and Corresponding Values'
Const _
REG_NONE      = 0 , _
REG_SZ        = 1 , _
REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2 , _
REG_BINARY    = 3 , _
REG_DWORD     = 4 , _
REG_MULTI_SZ  = 7

'Registry Subtrees and Corresponding Hexadecimal Values'
Const _
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT   = &H80000000 , _
HKEY_CURRENT_USER   = &H80000001 , _
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE  = &H80000002 , _
HKEY_USERS          = &H80000003 , _
HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000005 , _
HKEY_DYN_DATA       = &H80000006

'Abbreviated names for Registry Subtrees
Const HKCR = &H80000000 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
Const HKCU = &H80000001 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Const HKUS = &H80000003 'HKEY_USERS
Const HKCC = &H80000005 'HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
Const HKDD = &H80000006 'HKEY_DYN_DATA
```